# How can I simulate the Gdal translate scale function via code to manually change a 16 bit array

Tags: gdal-translate

I know how to use the Gdal scale function but I would prefer not to use Gdal.  I have a Uint16Array array representing pixels for  png image used as a heightmap. Currently I use Gdal to scale the image as such.

```
-scale [image.min image.max [32767 65535]]
```

This basically gives me a range of -32767 to +32767.

Instead of using Gdal what formula could I apply to the pixel values in my array to get the same results.  I am using javascript to manipulate the array but any example will do.

Comment: Did you look at the gdal code?

Comment: Yes but I can't figure out what is actually being applied in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/368166cbebcb1fe94766be68850524741a7a41a1/apps/gdal_translate_lib.cpp#L65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your input values range from src_min to src_max and your desired output values range from dst_min to dst_max. You need to compute two terms, offset and scale such that for any input value v,

```
(v - src_min) * scale + offset
```

this can be trivially solved by observing the two bounding cases.

Case 1:

```
(src_min - src_min) * scale + offset = dst_min 
offset = dst_min
```

Case 2:

```
(src_max - src_min) * scale + offset = dst_max
(src_max - src_min) * scale + dst_min = dst_max
(src_max - src_min) * scale = dst_max - dst_min
```

That's the general form, but you have to account for special cases that will lead to divide by zero to have solid code.
scale = (dst_max - dst_min)/(src_max - src_min)

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you are computing the offset.  So if I understand correctly then  scale = (dst_max - dst_min)/(src_max - src_min).  Then for each value v in my array I apply (v - src_min) * scale + offset.  Are you saying dst_min = offeset? So the formula would be (v - src_min) * scale + dst_min?

Comment: @dan - that's right

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [min/max normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling_(min-max_normalization)):

Scaling 0-1

[image]

Scaling arbitrary set of values a-b

[image]

A python numpy array example:

```
def rescale(array, out_min=0, out_max=1):
    arr_min, arr_max = array.min(), array.max()
    return out_min + (
        ((array - arr_min) * (out_max - out_min))
        /
        (arr_max - arr_min)
    )
```